# How to remove the last character of a word in a text string and insert to another cell using VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Everything is working except for that little comma in the 5th word. How to remove that? My code is as follows.

The text looks like this: `The data as of 20.12.2019, and so on.`
I only want `20.12.2019` without that comma. Any clue? Thanks.

```
Public Function FindWord(Source As String, Position As Integer)

Dim arr() As String
arr = VBA.Split(Source, " ")
xCount = UBound(arr)
If xCount < 1 Or (Position - 1) > xCount Or Position < 0 Then
    FindWord = ""
Else
    FindWord = arr(Position - 1)
End If
End Function
```

subroutine calls the function.

```
Sub InsertDate()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = FindWord(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2"), 5)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this pattern always the same > your data just before a comma?. If not, something simple like `RegEx` will do the job quite nicely

Comment: A formula solution is to use left() with len(), so left(A1,len(A1)-1)

Comment: The pattern is the same. Always the fifth word in that text string. What RegEx?

Comment: By `RegEx` I meant a regular expression to catch a substring in your whole string that follows a certain pattern. In your case something like: `\b(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})`

Comment: Another way `myar = Split(Replace(YOURSTRING, ",", ""), " ")` and then `Debug.Print myar(4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to `Replace`:

```
Sub InsertDate()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
        .Value = FindWord(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2"), 5)
        .Value = Replace(.Value, ",", "")
    End With
End Sub
```

This is still *text-that-looks-like-a-date*, so you can call `DateValue` to convert it.

```
.Value = Replace(.Value, ",", "")
.Value = DateValue(.Value) '<~ add this line
```

Comment: There is a small catch. The value inserted to the cell shifted slighted to the left side of the cell. I suspect it's not a real number inserted rather a text. Any way to correct this? On the Excel sheet, I double clicked that cell and hit Enter, it shifted to the right side. It was recognized a Number instead of Text, I guess. So something is not inserted as it supposed to, if you know what I mean?

Comment: It is text - you could probably use `DateValue` on it.

Answer (score 4):

So just for fun, a short introduction to regular expressions (which, by no means, I am an expert in):

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "The data as of 20.12.2019, and so on."
Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

regex.Pattern = "\b(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})"
regex.Global = True

Debug.Print regex.Execute(str)(0)

End Sub
```

This would be good practice if your string won't follow that same pattern all the time. However when it does, there are some other good alternatives mentioned in comments and answers.

Comment: This solution seems better as it will look for definite pattern irrespective of position. Of course, OP has stated his requirement differently.